# C#, in a class, how to return value for a datagridview.Rows.Add(...........)?

Tags: c#, oop, class, datagridview, return

```
public string GetInfo()
    {
        return a + b + c;
    }
```

this is used for display in a listbox, i think.

but for a datagridview, it should be "datagridview.Rows.Add(a, b, c)"

so what about the "," in my class?

thanks!

Comment: Congratulations, you have just earned the least understandable question award.

Comment: Your datagridview has three columns and the column values are a,b and c, is it?  I am trying to understand your question.

Comment: yes, Sachin, that is what i mean!

Comment: @user2049259 I have posted my answer you can look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you want return multiple values from function then do not concatenate them in single string*

So there are couple of way to do this

**First** (prefer this): Make a Class having these property like this

```
Public class MyValues
{
  public string valueA { get; set; }
  public string valueB { get; set; }
  public string valueC { get; set; }
}
```

Make a function Which return above class object or list of object

```
 public List<MyValues> GetInfo()
   {
   List<MyValues> listValue=new List<MyValues>();

   // Now here make myValue object and add them into listValue and then return
   return listValue;
   }
```

Now you can use it like this

```
List<MyValues> values=GetInfo();
foreach(MyValue val in values)
{
   datagridviewrow.Row.Add(val.ValueA,val.ValueB,val.ValueC)
}
```

**Second**: Make your function which returns List like this

```
    public List<string> GetInfo()
    {
       List<string> myValues=new List<string>{a,b,c}
       return myValues
    }
```

Now add them in DataGridViewRow like this

```
List<string> rowsValues=GetInfo();
datagridview.Rows.Add(rowValues[0],rowValues[1], rowValues[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine(a + "," + b + "," + c); maybe if you are asking what im thinking

Comment: thanks, but i want to add a row to a datagridview, so i need write datagridview.Rows.Add(a, b, c) to add a row " a  b  c"